# ISNULL function confusion

Tags: sql

l am wondering about what “=YES” means

```
case when ISNULL (sales_id, ‘NO’) =‘YES’ then 1 else 0;
```

I got what ISNULL means but the remaining part after yes is little confusing to get.

Comment: It's `CASE WHEN <expression> THEN <expression> ELSE <expression>;` probably, in which case you're comparing `saled_id` with `YES` and returning 1 or 0. (horribly named field though if it's supposed to have the values `YES` or `NO`)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen So even if the expression returns NO then that’s =YES?

Comment: It is *compared* to `YES`, correct, that's what the equals sign is doing here, comparing. But see Gordon's answer below, I suspect there is some confusion about what `ISNULL` actually does.

Comment: What database product is this for, and what's the data type of `SALES_ID`?

Comment: It essentially need not be complex. That `NO` must have confused you. Take a look at  this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @BobJarvis Varchar(3)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I got confused by YES actually.. If we are replacing null with NO then why there is =YES is the confusion

Comment: its either `<sales_id> = 'YES'` or `'NO' = 'YES'` so false in every case except your `<sales_id>` is `YES` anywhere. Makes no sense in my head, what am i missing? :D

Comment: This is the way I'll have wrote it: `CASE WHEN COALESCE(sales_id,'NO') = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` just because using coalesce is, at least to me, less confusing then using `IFNULL` but behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This logic is exactly equivalent to:

```
(case when sales_id = 'YES' then 1 else 0 end);
```

(well, this fixes a syntax error -- the missing `end`)

The `isnull()` is doing nothing, because a `null` value doesn't match anyway.  The more common function for this purpose is `coalesce()`.

Note:  This assumes that `sales_id` is a string.  I suspect the logic that is actually intended is:

```
(case when sales_id is not null then 1 else 0 end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's ignore, for a moment, the presence of the `IFNULL` call. If we do so we get

```
CASE WHEN SALES_ID = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

What this CASE expression is doing is translating a 'YES' in the SALES_ID column to 1, and translating any other non-NULL value in the SALES_ID column to 0. Without further context I don't know *why* this is being done, but that's the purpose of this expression.

The `IFNULL` call is needed because apparently SALES_ID can be NULL, and because of the way NULL is treated in a comparison or other operation. Think of it this way: NULLs are poison. *Any* operation with NULL returns NULL. Adding NULL to a number returns NULL. Multiplying by, dividing by, or subtracting NULL returns...NULL. NULLs poison operations. Comparisons work the same way - a comparison with NULL returns NULL. Not "equal". Not "not equal". The comparison returns NULL. So we don't want to do operations or comparisons with NULL because it will cause our code to do strange things - mostly, we'll get back NULL where we expected to get something else, and that will cause us to scratch our heads, pound our fists upon the table, scream, shout, cry, laugh (maniacally), contemplate calling down the wrath of (your favorite deity) from upon high, etc. So, we don't want to do operations on NULL. So to avoid all these potentially bad results (although, y'know, every once in a while I think that a little wrath-o-god unleashed upon some of my co-workers would be...appropriate...but, still... :-) we use `IFNULL`. In this case, `IFNULL(SALES_ID, 'NO')` means "If SALES_ID is NULL, give me back 'NO'. Otherwise, give me back the value of SALES_ID, whatever that may be".

So, there you are. Best of luck.